# svcUtil error 'SchemaLocation' must successfully resolve if <redefine> contains any child other than <annotation>

Tags: .net, wcf, svcutil.exe

I am trying to generate a proxy from a 3rd party wsdl and xsd files.  I am calling svcutil like so:

```
svcutil *.wsdl *.xsd /language:C#
```

It returns this error: 'SchemaLocation' must successfully resolve if  contains any child other than .

There is only one  element in all the files, and it's schemaLocation attribute points to another file in the same directory.  I tried fully qualifying the uri, but that did not help.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error was caused by an unrelated problem with the wsdl file.  The portType operation parameters were named, but the binding operation peramters were not.  When I fixed this svcutil generated the proxy, so I assume it must have been able to find the proper xsd includes.